# Deactivating Outlook window for a custom form

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I'm currently writing an add-in where a pop-up box of choices appears when a certain action takes place.  I'd like to make it so that the user can't continue in Outlook until they've either made a choice or cancelled the pop-up window.

I know how to do this for a static windows form-based application but seem to be running into difficulty and few answers (my google-fu is not coming up with anything right now).

Advice and assistance are welcome as always,
Larry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [`ShowDialog()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx).

Comment: Cripes!  That loud sound you just heard was my head hitting my desk.  Thanks, SLaks!